# Expose filter like google

Tags: 6, views

I create a views and filter node title , with expose filter.
how to change it to work like Google . don't have apply button and filter on time.
is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I know you can get by doing just site buiding is by using the [views autocomplete filters module](http://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) which gives the possibility of using an autocomplete widget for the exposed filter by simply checking an option in the exposed filter options in the view.